# Ciphermail installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Wanted to try Ciphermail.

I installed Ubuntu server 16.04

openjdk-7 wasn't available in Ubutun 16.04 so I added the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

Then I just followed everything, step by step, from this:
https://www.ciphermail.com/documents/quick-install-guide.pdf

In the end, I get the Tomcat "The requested resource is not available" message:

```
type Status report
message /ciphermail
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I don't see anything relevant in /var/log/djigzo.log
or in /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

Except maybe this:

```
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
```

Or maybe I don't know what to look for.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CipherMail can also use OpenJDK 8 instead of OpenJDK 7.

I tested the installation on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 installation. I followed the installation procedure from the quick install guide:

https://www.ciphermail.com/documents/quick-install-guide.txt

I only replaced openjdk-7 with openjdk-8:

sudo apt-get install postgresql postfix openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless ant ant-optional mktemp wget libsasl2-modules symlinks

Everything worked without any problems.